# Repeat Javascript Function in PHP foreach loop

Tags: javascript, php, for-loop, foreach

I have a Javascript function within a row in a foreach loop. I'd like to have it repeat each row and have tried this code. Each row has a element ID baserate which will be converted using the code below.

My problem is that it works only on the first row and doesn't for the rest. I do need some help to solve this, and any help is appreciated.

PHP:

foreach ($alllocs as $allrows) - no need to put complete code here.

JAVASCRIPT:

```
<script>     
  for (var i = 0; i < <?php echo $alllocs; ?>.length; i++) { 
    var a = document.getElementById("baserate").value;
    var e = Number(a).toFixed(2); 
    var b = Number(forex.rates.KRW).toFixed(2); 
    var c = e * b;     
    document.getElementById("welkomet").innerHTML = (c).toFixed(2);
  }  
</script>
```

Comment: `$alllocs` contains an array of PHP objects and you want to access the `$alllocs` in Javascript? Is that what you meant?

Comment: You may want to look at [json_encode($value)](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php) which converts $value to JSON representation, and [JSON.parse(text)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) which converts JSON text to `Javascript Object`

Answer (score 0):

I consider your foreach loop is like this

```
foreach ($alllocs as $allrows)
```

where You should replace `$alllocs` with `$allrows` in javascript code
so the code be like this

```
<?php
foreach ($alllocs as $allrows){
...
...
?>
<script>     
  for (var i = 0; i < <?php echo $allrows; ?>.length; i++) { 
    var a = document.getElementById("baserate").value;
    var e = Number(a).toFixed(2); 
    var b = Number(forex.rates.KRW).toFixed(2); 
    var c = e * b;     
    document.getElementById("welkomet").innerHTML = (c).toFixed(2);
  }  
</script> 
<?php
...
...
}
?>
```

cause `$alllocs` is an array(not a single value)

check this general form of foreach loop

```
foreach (array_expression as $value){
    statement
}
```